# How to request GPU quota increase in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've been trying to request an increase in my GPU quota for Compute Engine since Google Cloud says I have 0 when I try to launch an instance. I upgraded my account, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to increase my quota. I've looked at many tutorials, but the cloud platform has changed ever since those tutorials were released.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: A Google Cloud Issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63962807

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Similar to what Prateek said in the comments of Tuxdude's answer, the correct way to do is the following way:

Go to the quotas IAM & Admin Quotas page.

[image: IAM & Admin Quotas page]

If you look at the filtering options, you'll have "Quota type" and "Metric". Click on the "Quotas type" button and select "All quotas". This is important because since you currently have no GPU quota, the services containing the NVidia K80 GPUs will not show up. You can scroll down and find the service you want, which is a GPU in a specific zone. You don't have to, but you can now click on the Metric button, unselect all metrics, and click on the one that says NVidia K80 GPUs. Those services won't show up unless you click on "All quotas", though.

I would recommend that you go to Compute Engine -> VM Instance page and start the VM Instance creation process. On that page, you should check which GPU will be the cheapest for you (it depends on your location).

Comment: This is no longer accurate.  I don't see `Nvidia K80` in the list of metrics

Comment: Agreed! There's a deprecated Google Form, and several docs still link to it.  I did manage to see the K80 GPU in the list but it's not in the filter list, rather if you display all types and read carefully, it's still there

Comment: I am a DevOps eng with AWS certs, and I have to say that I am not at all impressed by Google Cloud.  Which is difficult to say since Google is the holy grail on most things for me.

Answer (score 22):

1. Go to [quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas).
   [image]
2. In Metrics column, deselect all and select the one with GPU
   [image]
3. Select the region for the GPU
4. Click on EDIT QUOTAS and then fill the form that pops up on the right-hand side
   [image]
5. Click on Submit request

You will get a response to your email after few minutes.

Comment: I just went through this process and received an email requesting a manual upfront payment, then requesting a reply email stating that I've made the payment.  Any idea what the process looks like from here and how long it will take?  Thanks.

Comment: @RyanChase The process was very fast without complications but I'm annoyed that the Quota limit / spending table isn't publically available.

Comment: I just requested a quota update of `GPUs (all regions)` from 0 to 1. I got the approval after a little more than 1 hour.

Comment: If you cant find the "metric" column, you need to press the "filter" button next to the  upsidedown triangle made of horizontal lines

Answer (score 11):

If you do not see the metric tab in your Quota page as shown below,

[image]

go to this url by changing the project name with id,

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?project=project-name-id-here&folder&organizationId&metric=GPUs%20(all%20regions)&location=GLOBAL

There you will find the GPU quota and you can select the checkbox and press edit quotas and proceed.

for further help you can visit this site

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/63962807

Comment: THIS should be the top rated answer. Thank you so much, Gayal.

Comment: This is the most general request for GPUs and the most useful. Thanks @gayal

Answer (score 6):

For poeple unable to find the mysterious drop-down menu to select "Service", "Limit Name" and "Location", click the upside down triangle on top of the check box of the first row of your quotas table. The menu should manifest afterward.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem with finding GPU quotas :)

Answer (score 3):

The steps Jacques outlined are correct.  But they may not work unless you clear your cookies or use a browser in incognito mode.  Apparently this is a known issue for google cloud.[what google cloud support said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iosze.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can request additional quota from the [Quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/quotas?_ga=1.267820684.389402746.1500597250) in the Google Cloud Platform Console UI page.

> ### [Requesting additional quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota)
>
> Request additional quota from the [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/quotas?_ga=1.267820684.389402746.1500597250) page in the Cloud
>   Platform Console.
>
> [**GO TO THE QUOTAS PAGE**](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/quotas?_ga=1.62370478.389402746.1500597250)
>
> You will receive a response from the Compute Engine team within 24 to
>   48 hours of your request.
>
> We strongly recommend planning and requesting additional resources at
>   least a few days in advance to ensure that there is enough time to
>   fulfill your request.

Also, if you are using the free trial you do not have any GPU quota.

> ### [GPUs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#gpus)
>
> Similar to virtual CPU quota, GPU quota refers to the total number of
>   virtual GPUs in all VM instances in a region. Check the [quotas
>   page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/quotas?_ga=1.4643377.389402746.1500597250) to ensure that you have enough GPUs available in your project
>   and request a quota increase. Free Trial accounts do not receive GPU
>   quota by default.

Comment: This is what I've been trying. The quotas page leads me to a form that doesn't work with GPUs any longer. The form tells me to head to https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6075746 which in turn tells me to go the Cloud Console to Edit Quotas. None of this works to increase quotas.

Comment: The OP is right. The old google form is deprecated and it asks you to edit quota from the google cloud console. Only there is no option for GPU's over there meaning you're stuck.

Comment: Actually I found it in the settings, filter metrics for NVDIA K80 GPU.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find any item listed below by changing the filter conditions of "Quota Type" and "Metric", you can try to find it manually.

Select "**All quotas**" for "Quota Type", after all the items listed below, you can use **ctrl + f** to find "GPU" page by page, until you find the one with **GPU** and the location is "**Global**".

Answer (score 0):

Have not seen mentioned in other answers so in addition to checking your quota status (using the console or `gcloud compute regions describe <region-name>` also check you're creating the VM in a **region and zone** that has GPUs available.

You can check availability here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones

This had me stumped for a bit as the quota metrics showed available quota in europe-west3 but that region only has (at the time of this answer) GPUs in zone b. Also GPU type availability varies by zone.
The auto selected zone on the console VM creation page is zone c so the option for adding GPUs was greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way of doing this has been continually changing and none of the current answers show exactly how to do this.

You need to first go to IAM & Admin:

[image: Click IAM & Admin]

Then find the Quotas at the very bottom on the left navigation pane:

[image: Select quotas]

Then go to the filter and find "Limit name":

[image: Finding Limit Name]

Then start typing "GP" and you should see "GPUS-ALL-REGIONS-per-project" (name will probably change)

[image: Select GPUS-ALL-REGIONS-per-project]

If you are using the free trial, you might not be allowed to select:
[image]

In this case, you need to upgrade your account to paid (although you should still be able to use your trial funds).