# Google Cloud Platform GPU Quotas not always displayed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota

I am using GCP with several identical projects. For each new project I need a
quota of one GPU (Tesla K80). In order to apply for an increase of my GPU quota, I open the [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and navigate to "IAM & Admin" > "Quotas". There I filter for my region (europe-west-1) and look for the "NVidia K80 GPUs" entry.

I have noticed that the Compute Engine APIs only appear after visiting the "Compute Engine" menu at least once. So far so good. However, the option for the GPUs only shows up after a lot of browsing around and switching between projects and revisiting the quotas page. It seems completely random.

Here is an example of two identical projects and the available quota options:

Project "**examplestudent02**" has the GPU option:

[image: project with GPU option]

Project "**examplestudent03**" does **not** have the GPU option:

[image: project without GPU option]

I cannot figure out what makes this option appear. Did anyone experience something similar? Is there something that needs to be activated before the GPU quota option appears?

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227064/how-to-request-gpu-quota-increase-in-google-cloud) on stack overflow. However, the GPU option also does not appear when changing the Quota type to "All quotas" (which is the default anyway). Also going to the quotas page in incognito mode did not help. Lastly, I normally use Chrome, but I also tried logging in with a different browser (Firefox) which also did not help.

Comment: Going to *Compute Engine > Quotas*, and then clicking on the "IAM & Admin Quotas page" link, instead of going to this menu directly through *IAM & Admin > Quotas*, appears to fix the issue sometimes. However, this does not work reliably either.

Comment: I have almost the same issue. There is no GPU quota at all (I've upgraded my account)

Comment: For anyone following this question: I got feed-back from the GCP support. Apparently this is a known issue and they are currently working on a fix. They also suggested trying deleting cookies or using private mode as in the related question above. These didn't work for me unfortunately, but maybe it works for other people. If you want updates on the progress of the fix, best submit your own question through the GCP technical support form.

Comment: I was not able to see the GPU quota in the list as well, but now it can be successfully shown. I submitted the request and got the approval immediately.

Comment: I noticed that the K80 gpu quota appears in my projects only after I went to the firewall exceptions page. This has worked consistently so far for all my projects. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The following answer is based on the current scenario as there is no issue with quota display anymore.

To answer to your question, you can go to the [quotas page of your console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.177217196.861218482.1516056063-144889312.1508510367&_gac=1.37490580.1513969532.EAIaIQobChMIpPH36Kee2AIVleNkCh3omAl0EAAYASABEgIPHPD_BwE)  and check your GPU quota from there. 
The GPUs are currently listed by the name of *NVIDIA K80 GPUs* and *NVIDIA P100 GPUs* (not GPU only). These can be easily filtered out by selecting from ***Metric*** column on this page.

If any of these cannot be found then the quota might not have been assigned. To request the GPU quota, you can follow the [steps mentioned in this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota). Once the request is submitted, it might take 24 to 48 hours to get approved.

That being said, one thing you need to keep in mind that free trial accounts **do not receive GPU quota** [by default](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#gpus). I would also suggest [checking the restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions) on instances with GPU to avoid any future issues.

Hope this helps.