# Moving an google cloud vm instance gives error Code '6562453592928582321' and instance is gone

Tags: google-cloud-platform

After executing

```
gcloud compute instances move instance-ba --zone us-east1-b --destination-zone us-east1-c
```

and waiting for about 5 minutes the following error was thrown

```
Moving gce instance instance-ba...failed.
ERROR: (cloud.compute.instances.move) Code: '6562453592928582321'
```

and the instance was gone from the web interface as well as from zone us-east1-b and us-east1-c

I tried to start the instance with

```
cloud compute instances start instance-ba --zone us-east1-b
```

and

```
cloud compute instances start instance-ba --zone us-east1-c
```

but none was working.

Thank you in advance for your help.
I have to say that this instance is quite important and I appreciate every input to solve this issue.

**Edit**

In the Stackdriver Logging I am seeing the following commands executed alternating:

- Compute Engine setDiskAutoDelete us-east1-b:instance-ba
- compute.instances.setDiskAutoDelete

As it seems the instance has been deleted from us-east1-b but not transferred to us-east1-c.

I do not see any error at all. All logs have severity "INFO" or lower.

**Edit 2**

I recall my steps which preceeded the moving error as follows

- I tried adding a second Tesla P100 to my instance which gave at startup the error that the resources are not enough to fulfill the request
- I tried moving the instance which gave the "TERMINATED" error so I
- tried to reset the machine with the reset command which gave the "instance not ready" error
- I removed the second Tesla P100 so that I could start the machine
- I did the restart command over and over until it worked and the machine was able to start
- Since I needed a second GPU I tried to moved this instance (without the second GPU) from us-east1-b to us-east1-c which finally did not work and gave the error

**Edit 3**

After some research I found that the procedure actually made a snapshot from my instance and the data is not lost.

However I will keep this question updated concerning the error and the response to it from google.

Comment: 1) Does Stackdriver show anything? 2) Open a support ticket with Google even if you must pay for a support subscription - appeal the charges later. 3) Please update this thread if you learn anything.

Comment: @John Hanley
1) I updated the question regarding the Stackdriver but the error is not shown in the log
2) I will open an support ticket
Thanks for your support.

Comment: Is there any settings that you made on the instance at creation? I just moved an instance several times with no issue.

Comment: I edited my answers giving the steps that preceded the moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#choosing_between_a_manual_and_automatic_move), you have a short specification for when to use the manual or the automatic move. As the procedure says, use the manual move when:

"Your VM is not RUNNING."

"You are moving your VM to a different region and your VM belongs to a subnetwork."

"Your instance has GPUs or local SSDs attached."

In your case, you had one GPU attached to your instance. So the correct way to move it is the following:

1. Stop your instance
2. Edit the instance, on the “Machine type” click customize and select “none” numbers of GPU. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#add-gpu-to-instance).
3. Start your instance
4. Use the gcloud command to [move the instance between zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#choosing_between_a_manual_and_automatic_move):

> $ gcloud compute instances move example-instance --zone us-central1-a --destination-zone us-central1-f

5. Once the instance is migrated stop it again.
6. Add the GPU and start the instance.

Keep in mind that every zone has different [GPUs available](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#gpus-list) and new projects have [limits for GPUs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions).

"To protect Compute Engine systems and users, new projects have a global GPU quota, which limits the total number of GPUs you can create in any supported zone. When you request a GPU quota, you must request a quota for the GPU models that you want to create in each region, and an additional global quota for the total number of GPUs of all types in all zones."

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think you did a good gob summarizing the procedure. Nevertheless I have to say that my procedure (with detours) was similar to yours (see Edit 2).

Comment: You can have 2 Tesla P100 on us-east1-b, you are getting the error "resources are not enough to fulfil the request" because you have limits for GPUs. Check [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions). "you must request a quota for the GPU models that you want to create in each region". There is a [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227064/how-to-request-gpu-quota-increase-in-google-cloud) for requesting quota for GPU.

Comment: Oh I think now I get what you are saying. It would have been possible to start the instance in the region but my quota was too small.
Do you think this fact has to do with the error code given above (but I removed the GPUs and still got the error)?

Comment: Just to give some more information: I opened an issue at Issue Tracker. About a week ago the error above got replicated (by moving an instance between two regions). I will keep this thread updated. In the meantime I solved my problem (by creating a new instance from the snapshot) and requested the quota (see Edit 3).

Comment: I keep thinking that the first error that you get was for trying to move the instance with a GPU attached to it and the second one was for not having enough quota. The post is for the error "6562453592928582321" as my answer for evading it. I recommend you to open another question for the second error.

Comment: You mean by first error "TERMINATED" and second error "6562453592928582321"?

Comment: First error "6562453592928582321", that happens if you migrate an instance with a GPU attached.
Second error "resources are not enough to fulfil the request": happens when you don't have enough quota and you need to [ask for quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota)

Comment: So you are saying, the error "6562453592928582321" happened because I tried to move the _instance with GPU_? I think this comment does answer the question. If you post this as answer/edit your answer I will accept it. I do not accept your current answer since it does not refer to my problem.

Comment: Exactly, I recreated It myself and if you don't remove the GPU before migrating you will get this error. That is why I answer with the right procedure for migrating machines with GPU's attached.

Comment: I will mark your question as answer. Nevertheless it would be more helpful if you directly referenced the errors since in the question more than one error was mentioned.