# How to increase the Socket Connect Count quota for app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

There's a hard limit on the socket connect count for GAE https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas. The number 3M per day seems relatively low for any largish scale project. I'm calling into Google Drive APIs (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/) from java and hitting against the limit for my project. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for a quota increase request to Google but keep in mind that your account must not be a free trial to do it and that in some regions this is not possible. In your request you must to explain the reason why you need the quota increase.

Once you submit the request, it will be take until 3 business days to apply the change.

You can take a look at this link [Request a quota increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227064/how-to-request-gpu-quota-increase-in-google-cloud) to know how to request a quota increase. You only must to replace ‘GPU’ for ‘Socket receive count per day’