# Is there a sockets quota for cloud run?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

As described in [How to increase the Socket Connect Count quota for app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614948/how-to-increase-the-socket-connect-count-quota-for-app-engine) we had hit a quota limitation for GAE socket connect counts ( https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas). We end up creating new projects often, so it's a pain to ask for quota increases every time since it takes days. We were wondering if moving to Cloud run will fix this issue, since the quota page for cloud run does not say anything https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas. Just wondering if anyone has any experience on this front.

Comment: By sockets do you mean "Unix Sockets"? Cloud Run does not provide/create/manage sockets to containers except for the Cloud SQL Proxy. Any limitation that you might have will depend upon the OS in your container image. Note: I am posting this as a comment instead of an answer as I have not verified this thru actual testing. I do have very good knowledge of the internals of Cloud Run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no socket quotas for Cloud Run. Per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas), no such quotas exist. The documentation is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#grpc_websocket):

> Inbound WebSockets and gRPC streaming are not currently supported for
>   Cloud Run (fully managed). However, those protocols do work outbound
>   and unary gRPC is supported.