# Cannot spin up a simple dev project on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a trick to getting a quota increase for NVIDIA GPU's on GCP? Really can't believe the amount of red tape here. I'm going through a course on deploying KubeFlow via GCP and need 4 GPU
's for the distributed training module. GCP continually rejects any request over 1 GPU. Are there any Data Scientists actively using GCP for personal dev projects, who have had any luck?

Comment: Do you have a new GCP account?

Comment: I did create a project last Fall, but this particular project is just 5 days old.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus): "To protect Compute Engine systems and users, new projects have a global GPU quota, which limits the total number of GPUs you can create in any supported zone. When you request a GPU quota, you must request a quota for the GPU models that you want to create in each region, and an additional global quota for the total number of GPUs of all types in all zones."

Comment: Not finding any documentation on how to request those two additional GPU quotas ^^.  I did try and follow the steps here-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227064/how-to-request-gpu-quota-increase-in-google-cloud -- these requests continue to be rejected.

Comment: If Google is rejecting your quota increase, why do you think Stack Overflow can override their decision? You need to work with Google.

Comment: Noting here this was never resolved. Went back and forth between Sales team and Cust Support. Unable to obtain GPU. Sticking with AWS going fwd.