# How to request for GPU quota increase for Nvidia A100 (for AI Platform - Notebook)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gpu

I am currently trying out GCP before deciding if I would go on a paid service. I am currently on the $300 free trial version.

With the Machine Learning work that I am currently doing, using a GPU with only 16GB VRAM is insufficient. I am thinking of trying out the Nvidia A100 GPU which gives 40GB of VRAM.

However, when I tried to request for an Nvidia A100 quota increase from 0 to 1, I keep getting the email which says “Unfortunately, we are unable to grant you additional quota at this time”.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get access to Nvidia A100? Have I been doing something wrong when requesting the quota increase for Nvidia A100?

Many thanks in advance if anyone knows this and could help.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use GPUs with the free tier of GCP.

See https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier

> Your Free Trial credits apply to all Google Cloud resources, including Google Maps Platform usage, but with the following exceptions:
> You can't add GPUs to your VM instances.

Comment: Thanks @James. I am also happy to pay for a paid service. However, I am still on the free trial account. Do you have any experience how I can request for Nvidia A100 at this point in time?

Comment: You could try upgrading to a paid version by pressing the "Present" Icon in the top right and clicking upgrade. However, I'd assume that since you are still technically using their trial credit. It won't let you. You could try increasing your quota by following this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227064/how-to-request-gpu-quota-increase-in-google-cloud.